# How can you figure out which answer to award the bounty to when you're not sure which one's better?

Tags: discussion

I asked the question:

[How can I make a custom progress bar for a YouTube embed animate smoothly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37582344/how-can-i-make-a-custom-progress-bar-for-a-youtube-embed-animate-smoothly)

and posted a bounty to gain more attention. Two good answers were posted, which both solved my problem.

- [answer by Alireza Ahmadi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37754755/5536767)
- [answer by Midas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37764572/5536767)

However, I was confident that one solution was better than the other, I just couldn't be sure which one it was without thoroughly testing each solution across various desktop and mobile browsers. The differences in the solutions weren't so simple that I could ask a new question "Which of these solutions will perform better across different browsers?". I hoped that people would vote on the answers and I could simply award the bounty to the most voted answer.

But few people voted, the answers each got only 1 vote, and eventually the bounty expired, so no one seems to have received a rep reward. In the future, is there something I can do to figure out which answer should be selected?

I've considered posting a question / asking for votes on the answers via Meta, but I'm not sure that would be well received or the correct usage of meta.

Comment: Pick the solution you actually used.  If after 4 days you still haven't tried any of them then just don't pick any of them.

Comment: Definitely don't post to meta asking for votes, especially not while the bounty it active.